# deploying redis to heroku unable to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque

ive been trying to get resque to work with heroku. i can successfully get it to work in development mode, however when i try pushing to heroku i get

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379):
```

i then read and followed http://blog.redistogo.com/2010/07/26/resque-with-redis-to-go/

i put the configurations listed in the site but got the following error

```
SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known):
```

i put in my initializers/resque.rb

```
Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }

ENV["redis://redistogo:11111111111111111@lab.redistogo.com:9254/"] ||= "redis://heroku_username:heroku_password@host:9254/"
uri = URI.parse(ENV["redis://redistogo:1111111111111111@lab.redistogo.com:9254/"])
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

however it throws the error mentioned above. on my dev mode now, i get the error as well.

i tried using my heroku username (im using the add on from heroku), putting my password to heroku, and changing the port to 9254. however i keep getting the socket error now. what am i doing wrong?

help would be much appreciated. thank you

UPDATE.

@kevin

i tried

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["my_url_string"] || "redis://localhost:9254/" )
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

in a initializer/redis.rb as well but i get the following error

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379):
```

are the numbers in the error, ie 127.0.0.1:6379 significant? ive checked my redis gui app and also from heroku config that my port number is 9254

```
REDISTOGO_URL       => redis://redistogo:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@lab.redistogo.com:9254/
```

did you have any other configuration settings? thanks for helping!

FINAL UPDATE.

i fixed it. i can't believe it! my complete solution is

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
Resque.redis = REDIS
```

verbatim. it works without explicitly setting the url because i guess heroku tries to set it up for me already

Comment: The final update made it work for me. It should go to `config/initializers/redis.rb`

Comment: Great! You saved my time. You should post your solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For my setup I have `/config/initializers/redis.rb` with these lines:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/" )
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

My `REDISTOGO_URL` is defined in my heroku configuration. You should be able to validate that by typing:

```
heroku config --app my_app
```

You'll see in the output the value for `REDISTOGO_URL`

You should copy your `REDISTOGO_URL` directly from Redis To Go. You find it in by going to the instance in heroku and clicking on Add Ons -> Redis To Go.

Here are a couple pointers:

1. Verify you have your REDIS_TO_GO URL in your heroku config from the command line like I've demonstrated above.
2. Verify the REDIS_TO_GO URL is identical to the one assigned to that instance in the Add Ons -> Redis To Go config.

Comment: yes ive checked using the command you said above and my url is matching. did you have any other initialization for redis? unfortunately i still get the error

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379):

Comment: i much appreciate your help = )

Comment: Remember to add before_fork and after_fork hooks if you are using unicorn. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#caveats

Also, Redis To Go docs: http://redistogo.com/documentation/resque

Comment: For me, i had to do `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp` to get it to read my ENV vars during deployment.

Answer (score 15):

i fixed it. i can't believe it! my complete solution is

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
Resque.redis = REDIS
```

verbatim. it works without explicitly setting the url because i guess heroku tries to set it up for me already

Answer (score 11):

I got the same thing, so, basically Sidekiq was not grabbing the REDISCLOUD_URL from vars, it was grabbing REDIS_PROVIDER.

```
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISCLOUD_URL
```

It worked like a charm.

Comment: heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL for me

Comment: heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL worked for me too (Rails 4)

Comment: heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL worked for as well too (Sinatra)